# If User sets Security setting in High mode from internet option. How to get Security mode in C# code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, settings, security

In my web application I calling webmethods using javascript/Jquery in asp.net c# web application,
If User sets Security setting in High mode then no any javascript runs on client machine 
it means Javascript goes disable. 
All the web methods going stopped running & no action take place..

If User set in IE8.0 browser

```
Goto Tools,
-> internet option 
-> security Tab
-> select Internet and set security mode to High
-> then It disabled Javascript.
```

How we get security mode setting by user in C#? 
If any alternate way to know that javascript is not enabled or change the mode!!
I want alert to if user set Internet security setting in **high mode/Medium High mode**..

-Thanks 
Abhishek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How we get security mode setting by user in C#?

You can't.

> If any alternate way to know that javascript is not enabled or change the mode

You could use the [`<noscript>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.3.1) HTML tag to provide alternate content when a script is not executed.

Comment: Thanks @Darin, How can I used <noscript> tag supposed java script is disabled then what to do ?

Comment: You put some alternate content inside this tag which will be shown to the user if he has javascript disabled telling him for example to change his browser settings.

Comment: Note that `<noscript>` is deprecated in html5 and not allowed at all in the xml version of html5.

Answer (score 1):

This is something you can only do at the client, typically by having a *working* site with script disabled, but *enhancing* the UI with script when available (perhaps replacing an anchor's click event with an AJAX call and cancel the default navigation).

You can also use `<noscript>` to remind the user that some features may be unavailable with their settings.